# How Charger and Cell Balancer work in BMS?

Tags: charger, bms, cell-balancing

I'm currently working on BMS for LiIon 4S2P battery pack. Two core components I've choose are [BQ77915 balancer](https://hr.mouser.com/ProductDetail/Texas-Instruments/BQ7791508PWR/?qs=DuoOggApuK8G2gN8HviVPQ%3D%3D) and [BQ2954](https://hr.mouser.com/ProductDetail/Texas-Instruments/BQ2954SNTR/?qs=YxwvVplHM%2FlXovkRVOO3Cg%3D%3D) charger from TI.

For now, I stick to example schemes from datasheets, but I'm curious about one thing:

**How to properly connect these two "systems"?**

Will charger think "*I'm not over with charging*" because balancer will be in proccess of balancing those cells? In other words, will charger know when his job is done, even while balancer is balancing cells?

Here is a scheme - example schemes connected.

[image]

Thanks for help!

Comment: Depends. How long does it stay in CV mode? Does the balancing manage to finish in that time?

Comment: @winny Balancing triggers at 3.8V. Charger is in CV mode until `Imin` is reached.
`The bq2954 then transitions to phase 2
and regulates constant voltage (VBAT = VREG) until the
charging current falls below the programmed IMIN
threshold` from datasheet.

Comment: Yes, so how long will that take and how long will your worst case imbalance take for your balancer to balance? Will it make it before the charger is done? If not, what SOC do you end up with and is this acceptable to you?

Comment: I'm not sure how long it will take because I don't have test board with it, only scheme.

Comment: Then you need to calculate that in order to tell if it’s a problem or not. As your question stands, it can’t be answered. If you take a look at commercial systems for this, it’s common for the charger to talk to the BMS to get around exactly these problems.